# How do I set Up a Cabal file?

Tags: cabal, nix, vscode, nixos

Whats a basic template I should use for cabal files that is easily customisable?

Answer (score 1):

It you run `cabal init` it will generate a template. You can also run it with the `--interactive` flag so that it asks you questions on what should go in the file.